# MongoDB - how do I remove _id:null from aggregate result?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I wondered if anyone can help? I am new to using MongoDB and am just learning about aggregates and projections. I am trying to average the results of **details.age**.

Finally I was able to work some code that gets the average result.

```
db.docs.aggregate([{$group: {_id:null, "Average": {$avg:"$details.age"} } }])
```

Does anyone know how I can remove the `"_id" : null` in the returned query result?

I have tried to remove "_id" : null from the query itself, but it is needed for the $group
I have also tried different permutations of the query inserting {_id:0} , _id:0, but I get errors.

QUERY

```
db.docs.aggregate([{$group: {_id:null, "Average": {$avg:"$details.age"} } }])
```

RESULT

```
{ "_id" : null, "Average" : 33 }
```

[image: Query returning "_id" : null]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add extra stage: `{$project:{_id:0}}` or `{$unset:"_id"}`

Comment: Thanks Valijon, I am just trying different permutations to add $project command to db.docs.aggregate([{$group: {_id:null, "Average": {$avg:"$details.age"},$project:{_id:0} } }]) any suggestions?

Comment: nooo. `db.docs.aggregate([{$group: {_id:null, "Average": {$avg:"$details.age"} } },{$project:{_id:0}}])`. Also, you may group by with empty string: `db.docs.aggregate([{$group: {_id:"", "Average": {$avg:"$details.age"} } }])`

Comment: Many thanks Valijon, your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You can just project that field off the result using a $project stage

```js
db.docs.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id:null, "Average": {$avg:"$details.age"} } },
    {$project: { _id: 0} }    
]);
```

If you're using MongoDB 4.2 you can use the $unset stage as well:

```js
db.docs.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id:null, "Average": {$avg:"$details.age"} } },
    {$unset: "_id" }    
]);
```